# Azure nodejs Api always returning The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable

Tags: node.js, azure, api

I am trying to host my angular nodejs app in Azure service, Angular front end is working fine ,but while trying to access the api i am always getting "The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable." The same code is working in locally .

[image: i have attached the file structure that i have hosted in azure]

Comment: Can you show the directory structure in the backend folder?

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code in `package.json` to start your project.

**[Solutions To Run Multiple Node.js or NPM Commands Simultaneously](https://itnext.io/4-solutions-to-run-multiple-node-js-or-npm-commands-simultaneously-9edaa6215a93)**

```
"scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "backend": "cd backend & npm run start",
    "frontend":"http-server dist/samplecode",
    "start": "start npm run frontend && start npm run backend",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
 },
```

**Test Result.（[Download test sample code](https://github.com/Jason446620/multiple_nodeproject)）**

1. Set backend port 4200, frontend port 8080.

   And we can found, two project all work.

   [image]

   [image]

   [image]
2. frontend and backend port use same port, 8080.

   We will find backend project is ok, and frontend has error.

   [image]

**3. The expected behavior is consistent with the result after deployment.**

## Suggestion

1. The front and back ends need to be separated, which is conducive to the maintenance and scalability of the project.
2. In azure app service, we can only use ports 80 and 443, so if the front and back ports are the same, there will be problems with the routing identification of the two projects. This is the problem you are currently experiencing.
3. If you only want to use one app services resource at present, the virtual application under windows cannot help you either, because the node project is deployed, and multiple projects cannot be started due to routing problems.

**4. If you have a storage account, you can deploy the front-end project in the static website and the backend project in the app service. This eliminates the need to create new services.**